# Rails 4 no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Have been reading through possible answers to this and can't find anything that will fix it.

I have a quotations table, a products table and a join tables quote_listings

**quotation model**

```
has_many :quote_listings
has_many :products, through: :quote_listings
accepts_nested_attributes_for :quote_listings
```

**product model**

```
has_many :quote_listings
has_many :quotations, through: :quote_listings
```

**quote_listing model**

```
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :quotation
```

**quotations_controller**

```
def new
  @quotation = Quotation.new
  @quotation.quote_listings.build
end

def quotation_params
  params.require(:quotation).permit(:id, :reference_number,:quote_date, :note, :client_id, :company_id, :user_id, :quote_listings_attributes[:id, :product_id])
end
```

**quotation _form view**

```
= f.fields_for :quote_listings do |builder|
  .field
    = builder.collection_select(:product_id, current_user.products, :id, :name, { :prompt => 'Select Product' })
```

**Error:** TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)

*When I look in rails panel I see this*

```
{"reference_number":"TG68297","quote_date(1i)":"2016","quote_date(2i)":"1","quote_date(3i)":"27","note":"Notes here","client_id":"6","company_id":"3","user_id":"2","quote_listings_attributes":{"0":{"product_id":"5","id":"1"}}}
```

I have hit a brick wall on this and can't figure out where I have gone wrong

**Full Stack Trace**

```
TypeError in QuotationsController#update
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Extracted source (around line #79):
77
78
79
80
81

    def quotation_params
      params.require(:quotation).permit(:id, :reference_number, :quote_date,
      :note, :client_id, :company_id, :user_id, :quote_listings_attributes[:id, :product_id])
    end
end

Rails.root: /home/projects_dev/assisq

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/quotations_controller.rb:79:in `[]'
app/controllers/quotations_controller.rb:79:in `quotation_params'
app/controllers/quotations_controller.rb:50:in `block in update'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:211:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/quotations_controller.rb:49:in `update'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
meta_request (0.3.4) lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
meta_request (0.3.4) lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
warden (1.2.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
rack-contrib (1.4.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'
meta_request (0.3.4) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
/home/visrez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/visrez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/visrez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Bkg4F/2hGmTcF2juW8NtvYKWj8OC1m5JBStfcpW+FZN+//9GCRuLg54KYvMz2Nu485+zkVFnoo44Kpdq2C9HYg==",
 "quotation"=>{"reference_number"=>"TG68297",
 "quote_date(1i)"=>"2016",
 "quote_date(2i)"=>"1",
 "quote_date(3i)"=>"27",
 "note"=>"Notes here",
 "client_id"=>"6",
 "company_id"=>"3",
 "user_id"=>"2",
 "quote_listings_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"product_id"=>"5",
 "id"=>"1"}}},
 "commit"=>"Save Quotation",
 "id"=>"7"}
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None
```

Comment: Can you add the full error trace?

Comment: Added the full stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo:

update this:

```
def quotation_params
  params.require(:quotation).permit(:id, :reference_number, :quote_date,
  :note, :client_id, :company_id, :user_id, :quote_listings_attributes[:id, :product_id])
end
```

to this:

```
def quotation_params
  params.require(:quotation).permit(:id, :reference_number, :quote_date,
  :note, :client_id, :company_id, :user_id, quote_listings_attributes: [:id, :product_id])
end
```

Comment: Amazing - I have been looking at this for hours and didn't spot that. Thanks very much.